# How to convert string from interface to []string in golang?

Tags: go

I'm parsing a JSON object which contains an array of strings :

```
var ii interface{}
json := "{\"aString\": [\"aaa_111\", \"bbb_222\"], \"whatever\":\"ccc\"}"

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json), &ii)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
data := ii.(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(data["aString"]) // outputs: ["aaa_111" "bbb_222"]
```

I tried to convert `data["aString"]` to []string to be able to loop over it, but it fails :

```
 test := []string(data["aString"]).([]string)
 fmt.Println(test) // panic -> interface conversion: 
                   //          interface is string, not []string
```

How can I convert `data["aString"]` ?

---

#### edit:

I didn't express myself properly. If I print `data`, I have such map :

`map[aString:["BBB-222","AAA-111"] whatever:ccc]`

I want to loop over aString (to manipule each array entry). But I can't find how, because aString is `type interface {}` :

```
for i, v := range aString { // <-- fails
     // ...
     fmt.Println(i, v)
}
```

That's why I want to convert aString. I don't want to convert a string which *looks like* an array to an array.

Comment: Do you know the exact structure of your JSON ? (Are the fields well defined or may they vary)

Comment: Your var `ii` should already be a `map[string]interface {}`... I see no reason to do the type assertion `data := ii.(map[string]interface {})`. Fixing that doesn't solve your problem, I just noticed it.

Comment: try this `aStringValue := ii.(map[string]interface {})["aString"]`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I recommend you move away from this implementation in general. Your json may vary but you can easily use objects and avoid all this type unsafe nonsense.

Anyway, that conversion doesn't work because the types inside the slice are not `string`, they're also `interface{}`. You have to iterate the collection then do a type assertion on each item like so:

```
aInterface := data["aString"].([]interface{})
aString := make([]string, len(aInterface))
for i, v := range aInterface {
    aString[i] = v.(string)
}
```

Comment: @jérôme, I'm with Evan on this, but if you really need to unmarshal your JSON data to maps (there are valid use cases for this), consider using the [`mxj` package](https://github.com/clbanning/mxj).

Comment: but that's exactly the problem... I can't loop over `data["aString"]` since it's `type interface {}`

Comment: @Jérôme ah, ok. So first you have to type assert on the `interface{}` to `[]interface{}` I can edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please update the second data["aString"] to be aInterface. It then works :-)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, pretty good chunk of code but a tiny mistake, you append to aString array, which is already allocated to the good size. Just assign it:  `aString[i] = v.(string)` [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VW4hDLY_1j8)

Comment: @Sylvain yeah, agreed. small optimizations matter a lot at scale. edited with the better solution.

Comment: doesn't work if one of the values is int.

Answer (score 5):

Is it what you need?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    js := "{\"aString\": [\"aaa_111\", \"bbb_222\"], \"whatever\":\"ccc\"}"
    a := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &a)
    for _, v := range a["aString"].([]interface{}) {
        str := v.(string)
        fmt.Println(str)
    }
}
```

Check on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/G7PnOiEc1w)

Answer (score 0):

For another approach, you can use a `struct` instead:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   s := []byte(`{"aString": ["aaa_111", "bbb_222"], "whatever":"ccc"}`)
   var t struct {
      Astring []string
      Whatever string
   }
   json.Unmarshal(s, &t)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t) // {Astring:[aaa_111 bbb_222] Whatever:ccc}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving that by just Marshall and Unmarshall:

```
type Paragraph struct {
    Paragraph_id          string    `json:"paragraph_id"`
    Parent_document_id    string    `json:"parent_document_id"`
    Page_in_document      int       `json:"page_in_document"`
    Text                  string    `json:"text"`
    Previous_paragraph_id string    `json:"previous_paragraph_id"`
    Parent_paragraph_id   string    `json:"parent_paragraph_id"`
    Child_paragraph_ids   []string  `json:"child_paragraph_ids"`
    Next_paragraph_id     string    `json:"next_paragraph_id"`
    Summary               string    `json:"summary"`
    Vector                []float64 `json:"vector"`
    Definitions           []string  `json:"definitions"`
    Keywords              []string  `json:"keywords"`
    IsLeaf                bool      `json:"leaf"`
}

_, err := session.ExecuteRead(db_ctx, func(transaction neo4j.ManagedTransaction) (any, error) {
        result, _:= transaction.Run(db_ctx,
            "MATCH (paragraph:Paragraph) RETURN paragraph",
            map[string]any{},
        )

    paragraphs = []Paragraph{}

    for result.Next(db_ctx) {
            record := result.Record()       
            para, _ := record.Get("paragraph")
            properties := para.(neo4j.Node).GetProperties()
            bytes, _ := json.Marshal(properties)

            var paragraph knowledge_structs.Paragraph
            json.Unmarshal(bytes, &paragraph)

            paragraphs = append(paragraphs, paragraph)
}
```

Not sure how efficient it is ;)